# InputStream.close very slow if download size is huge

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
HttpGet downloadRequest = new HttpGet("url?size=10000000");
HttpResponse response = this.httpClient.execute(downloadRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();        
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

while ((length = (int)inputStream.skip((long)BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0) {

 ...
}

inputStream.close();
```

It is a very basic program which downloads data from a url. My question is that it is working fine if it finishes downloading all the data; however, if I try to force to stop the download progress(e.g. break the while loop after 1 sec) midway,

```
inputStream.close();
```

takes long time to close the inputStream. And the more downloaded data it left, the more time it took to close it.

Does I do anything wrong when I close the inputStream? Is there a way to close the inputStream right away safety which no matter how much data left in "inputStream"?

Comment: Are you sure this has to do with InputStream itself? I couldn't reproduce this behavior locally.
Could it have something to do with this?

" IMPORTANT: Please note all entity implementations must ensure that all allocated resources are properly deallocated after the InputStream.close() method is invoked."

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29

Have a look here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818169/usage-of-consumecontent-of-httpentity

Maybe you should call EntityUtils.consume(HttpEntity) instead?

Comment: I tried EntityUtils.consume(HttpEntity) before and got the same problem as close inputStream

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what helped me was to issue a `httpget.abort()` before closing the `InputStream` and before issuing `EntityUtils.consume(entity)`.

`httpget.reset()` should have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem dealing with Post request. I traced into and found out what caused the HttpResponse hung was it is still streaming with large data.
The fix was to abort the request from the beginning. Something similar like following

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("request/endpoint");
httpPost.abort();
// do the rest down here
```