# HttpClient execute hanging Android application

Tags: android, httpclient

I am developing an Android application, which populates its ListView after getting and parsing the data from a web service. Below is the **AsyncTask** code which I am using.

```
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        Integer result = 0;
        try {
            /* create Apache HttpClient */
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            /* HttpGet Method */
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

            /* optional request header */
            httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            /* optional request header */
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            /* Make http request call */
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                /* receive response as inputStream */
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
               // parseResult(response);
                result = 1; // Successful
            } else{
                Log.d(Tag, statusCode + " CODE");
                result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Tag, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
    }
```

The application is hanging at `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);`

What is wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you calling AsyncHttpTask ?

Comment: new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url); from onCreate of the activity.

Comment: are you sure your http endpoint is up and working ?
did you get any exception, :LogCat ?

Comment: I pasted the URL in browser and was able to get the response. There was no exceptions in the logcat. I put some log messages in the code and could find the execution is not going beyond HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

Comment: Have you  tried debugging? Where is it hanging? Do you have the correct permissions?

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access? Can you access that URL from the device you are testing? Add debug logging to make sure that the URL in `params[0]` is really the URL you think it is. Is `params` a `String` or a `URI`?

Comment: Its a String , the param. I am trying to access a private webservice. And the webservice and the url is accessible from the browser. But I also found something intersting lately. Instead of the url of my private webservice, I tried with some other url [the url was specified in some tutorials on httpclient android] and that was working fine. So what can be the problem with the url of my webservice?It is hanging exactly at HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);I put log messages before and after this line. Only the log message put before this line is coming.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this after you make your http request call

`HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();`

`entity.consumeContent();`

the details of consume content can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818169/usage-of-consumecontent-of-httpentity)